# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError - NDK in android studio gradle?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

Folder structure

```
 app 
---main
    ---java
    ----jni
          -----Android.mk
          -----Application.mk
          ----- hello-jni.c
    ---res
```

in build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hellojni"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 21
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'

    }

    ndk {
        moduleName "hello-jni"
        cFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions"
        ldLibs "log"
        stl "gnustl_shared"
        abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
    }

    task nativeLibsToJar(type: Zip, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
        destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
        baseName 'native-libs'
        extension 'jar'
        from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
        into 'lib/'
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
    }







    testApplicationId "com.example.hellojni.tests"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
}


}
```

in Android.mk

```
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

in hello-jni.c

```
include<com.example.hellojni.HelloJni.h>

#include <string.h>
 #include <jni.h>



 jstring
 Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                              jobject thiz )
{
  #if defined(__arm__)
    #if defined(__ARM_ARCH_7A__)
      #if defined(__ARM_NEON__)
        #if defined(__ARM_PCS_VFP)
          #define ABI "armeabi-v7a/NEON (hard-float)"
        #else
          #define ABI "armeabi-v7a/NEON"
        #endif
          #else
           #if defined(__ARM_PCS_VFP)
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a (hard-float)"
         #else
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a"
       #endif
     #endif
   #else
   #define ABI "armeabi"
  #endif
 #elif defined(__i386__)
   #define ABI "x86"
  #elif defined(__x86_64__)
   #define ABI "x86_64"
  #elif defined(__mips64)  /* mips64el-* toolchain defines __mips__ too */
   #define ABI "mips64"
  #elif defined(__mips__)
   #define ABI "mips"
  #elif defined(__aarch64__)
   #define ABI "arm64-v8a"
#else
     #define ABI "unknown"
  #endif

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !  Compiled with ABI " ABI ".");
}
```

in java

```
  public class HelloJni extends Activity
 {
      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    TextView  tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText( stringFromJNI() );
    setContentView(tv);
}


public native String  stringFromJNI();


public native String  unimplementedStringFromJNI();


static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
}
}
```

I am getting unsatisfied error

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.hellojni-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libhello-jni.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
        at com.example.hellojni.HelloJni.<clinit>(HelloJni.java:64)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

My local.properties

```
sdk.dir=F\:\\SDK
ndk.dir=C\:\\NDK
```

Its not generating .so files ..

Comment: NDK with Android Studio is still a moving target, but the obvious check is to see if you are getting .so files in your apk.  Often it is easier to tell Android Studio to ignore it all, run ndk-build yourself, and drop the result wherever the latest version of Android Studio will find them.

Comment: @ChrisStratton how to run ndk-build myself?

Comment: See the ndk documentation of course.  It is an executable or script located in the root of the ndk installation folder, which you can run from a command line or build automation tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got several mistakes in your build.gradle:

The `nativeLibsToJar` task was a relevant technique in early versions of the gradle android plugin, It shouldn't be used since at least 0.7 and it may lead to bugs, remove this task. Instead, if you put your .so files inside `jniLibs/ABI` directories (where ABI is armeabi-v7a, x86...), they will get properly integrated inside your APK.

Then, you have set:

```
jni.srcDirs = []
jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
```

It deactivates the built-in ndk integration from the gradle plugin and make gradle use libs from `libs` instead of from `jniLibs`. That's fine, but later you're defining your ndk module with a `ndk {}` block, which is useless then, remove it.

Once you've cleaned these parts, you can call `ndk-build` (or `ndk-build.cmd` if you're using Windows) from command line, from the root of your Android project. It will generate your .so files inside `libs/ABI` and they will get integrated into your APK since `jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'` told gradle to get these libs from `libs`.

You can check that your .so files get integrated by opening your APK as a zip file; Your .so files have to be present under `lib/ABI`.