# How to convert JPEG images to TIFF format with G4 compression in Android?

Tags: java, android, compression, tiff

I am developing an android application and I want to be able to convert the camera pictures I take to tiff with Group 4 compression.

I tried using [this Android-ImageMagick library](http://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-ImageMagick), but I get the following error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError - NDK

I referred to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295180/) to solve but it didn't work.

Error occurs at the codes of library, Magick.java:43 line is the call of init(); method.
Since we use of Gradle in Android Studio, I strongly doubt that it’s because of Gradle. The explanation gave by the author of the library “how to use it” is based on project without Gradle.
If we change the name of method “init()” to another name like “test()”, the error occurs at other native method. 
Our structure of project:
and have added “ndk.dir” into local.properties, tried to add “sourceSets":

```
{
        main {
            jni.srcDirs=['jniLibs']
        }
    }
    ” at build.gradle.

    /**
     * The sole purchase of this class is to cause the native
     * library to be loaded whenever a concrete class is used
     * and provide utility methods.
     *
     * @author Eric Yeo
     * @author Max Kollegov &lt;virtual_max@geocities.com&gt;
     */
    public class Magick {

        static {
            /*String clprop = System.getProperty("jmagick.systemclassloader");
            if (clprop == null || clprop.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                try {
                    ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
                        .loadClass("magick.MagickLoader").newInstance();
                }
                catch(ClassN`enter code here`otFoundException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Can't load MagickLoader " +
                                               "(class not found)");
                }
                catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Access to SystemClassLoader "+
                                               "denied (IllegalAccessException)");
                }
                catch(InstantiationException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Can't instantiate MagicLoader " +
                                               "(InstantiationException)");
                }
            }
            else {
                System.loadLibrary("JMagick");
            }*/

            System.loadLibrary("imagemagick");

            init();
        }


        /**
         * Initializes the ImageMagic system
         */
        private static native void init();


        /**
         * Parses a geometry specification and returns the
         * width, height, x, and y values in the rectangle.
         * It also returns flags that indicates which of the
         * four values (width, height, xoffset, yoffset) were
         * located in the string, and whether the x and y values
         * are negative.  In addition, there are flags to report
         * any meta characters (%, !, <, and >).
         * @param geometry String containing the geometry specifications
         * @param rect The rectangle of values x, y, width and height
         * @return bitmask indicating the values in the geometry string
         * @see magick.GeometryFlags
         */
        public static native int parseImageGeometry(String geometry, Rectangle rect);

    }
```

This is the error I get:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.test.comp.magick.Magick.init:()V
            at com.test.comp.magick.Magick.init(Native Method)
            at com.test.comp.magick.Magick.<clinit>(Magick.java:43)
            at com.test.comp.magick.util.MagickBitmap.fromBitmap(MagickBitmap.java:41)
            at com.test.comp.activity.MainActivity.convertAndSendImage(MainActivity.java:60)
            at com.test.comp.activity.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:84)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3347)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please add more info, which library? Which issue is causing the integration not to work?

Comment: I tried using this library https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-ImageMagick
I get the following error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError - NDK, I referred to this stack overflow forum to solve but it didn' work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295180/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-ndk-in-android-studio-gradle

Comment: Thanks and please add relevant code.

Comment: Include pertinent information from the comments.

Comment: Thank you @Garry and Blackwood for your responses. I edited my post so that includes the maximum details

Comment: @Blackwood you can see my edit too. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

UnsatisfiedLinkError are thrown if ImageMagick library is not installed into your apk and causing linkage error:

Your library must be in directory `/project/libs/armeabi/`